How to get Matlab datatip to output subplot information?
I have a Matlab script which plots data in two subplots and allows me to click interactively on any data point using datatip and outputs the x,y info of that point. Running the code below, clicking on a data point using datatip and then pressing Enter will output the x,y value of that point in the Command Window. I can do this for any number of points till the loop ends or I manually close the figure window. Figure 1 and Figure 2 show me clicking on one point each from left and right subplot, respectively, and the information can be seen below at the bottom of the figures.
Is there a way in which I can make Matlab also output which subplot I am clicking on ? For example, it should output x,y, and 1 or 2 in which 1 or 2 are subplot indices.
Figure 1

Figure 2

clc
clearvars
close all

figure('units','normalized','Position',[0.15 0.45 0.7 0.55]);
for j1=1:2
    sbp1(j1)=subplot(1,2,j1);
    plot(1:1000,rand(1,1000),'k','linewidth',2);
    set(gca,'fontsize',24);
end
linkaxes(sbp1,'x');

datacursormode on;
dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn);

for rc11=1:10000
    try
        pause;
        info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
        if isfield(info_struct, 'Position')
            mkc1=info_struct.Position;
            fprintf('%.3f %.3f \n',mkc1(1),mkc1(2));
        end
    catch
        break;
    end
end

function output_txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj)
% ~            Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Object containing event data structure
% output_txt   Data cursor text
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {['x: ' num2str(pos(1))], ['y: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
end


A simple solution could be to use the UsderData propertyof the axes to hold the identifier of the axes.
You can add
set(gca,'UserData',['Axes #' num2str(j1)]);

in the loop that creates the subplots.
Then you can update the line that prints the position by adding the string held in the UserData
fprintf('%.3f %.3f \n%s\n',mkc1(1),mkc1(2),get(gca,'UserData'));

This is your code with the proposed solution.
clc
clearvars
close all

% figure('units','normalized','Position',[0.15 0.45 0.7 0.55]);
figure('units','normalized');
for j1=1:2
    sbp1(j1)=subplot(1,2,j1);
    plot(1:1000,rand(1,1000),'k','linewidth',2);
    set(gca,'fontsize',24);
    %
    % Set the identifier of the axes in the UserData property
    %
    set(gca,'UserData',['Axes #' num2str(j1)]);
    %
end
linkaxes(sbp1,'x');

datacursormode on;
dcm_obj = datacursormode(gcf);
set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn);

% for rc11=1:10000
for rc11=1:10000
    try
        pause;
        info_struct = getCursorInfo(dcm_obj);
        if isfield(info_struct, 'Position')
            mkc1=info_struct.Position;
%             fprintf('%.3f %.3f \n',mkc1(1),mkc1(2));
            %
            % Print the position and the axes identifier
            %
            fprintf('%.3f %.3f \n%s\n',mkc1(1),mkc1(2),get(gca,'UserData'));
            %
        end
    catch
        break;
    end
end

function output_txt = myupdatefcn(~,event_obj)
% ~            Currently not used (empty)
% event_obj    Object containing event data structure
% output_txt   Data cursor text
pos = get(event_obj, 'Position');
output_txt = {['x: ' num2str(pos(1))], ['y: ' num2str(pos(2))]};
end


